# Bash script cut and filename not hardcoded

Tags: linux, bash

I have a file called names.txt that looks like:

```
0,james,hard,fun,circle

1,caron,hard,agin,square
```

And I want to make it end up like:

```
james,hard,fun,circle,c0

caron,hard,agin,square,c1
```

I would like to run a script that asks for the file , and then make those changes to the file using the $1 argument and cut.

I know this is a hard question that may involve alot of code, so I truly appreciate your guys help.

NOTE: my file contains 9999 inputs and starts with first one being 0 , so 10,000 in total entry's.

Comment: could you write out the bash script for me sir?

Comment: Just put it into a file. That would be a bash script. A `bash` script is just one or more commands in a file that you can execute.

Comment: I would like to run a script that asks for the file , and then make those changes using the $1 argument and cut

Comment: I made the changes to my question

Comment: The simplest thing to do is use `$1` instead of `names.txt` as the argument in the script file. Then you can call your script, like `change names.txt` (if your script is called `change`). If you want to be fancy, you can look up how to check if an argument is blank and give a nicer error if the user doesn't provide an argument to the script.

Comment: I need to pass in my file name, and make use of cut if thats possible. Im not sure what to do sir, could you help me further?

Comment: That's how you pass it in. Read my previous comment carefully. Unless you mean something else by "pass in". Not sure why you keep saying you need `cut`. Is this a homework assignment and they say you have to use `cut`? If that's the case, please show a little effort to solve your problem. That's how you learn.

Comment: If you're passing the filename in $1, then the script doesn't "ask for it". Those are two separate ways of getting the filename to the script. Either you run it and it prompts you, or you run it with the filename as an argument (with `scriptname filename`, which puts the value "filename" into $1 inside the script).

Comment: oh makes sense I see, could you post a answer of the file and how it should looks exactly, ill test it right now myself. but i prefer not to use sed in the question, i would like to do it the longer way

Comment: This is not a homework service site. Try to write it yourself and ask a specific question if you run into trouble. But bash is fundamentally a command language; most of the real work is done by utilities like `sed` that the bash script executes.

Comment: Please do a little work. Most of the work has already been done for you in the comments. I am not going to post the answer with "how it should looks exactly". This is not a free homework writing service.

Comment: It is hard to say what is wrong with your code because you did not provide it or the errors you encountered. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: lurker take a look at some of these answers bro, they are clsoe but not quite there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a complete file that will modify the file in the way you ask and write It to the terminal, specifically to *standard out*, which is one of the "channels" that gets written to your terminal by default. (*channel* is not a technical term).

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -F, -vOFS=, '{print $0,"c" $1 }' "$1" | cut -d, -f2-
```

If the data contains blank lines in it, we can skip over them by adding a check in the `awk` fragment.

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -F, -vOFS=, 'NF > 0 {print $0,"c" $1 }' "$1" | cut -d, -f2-
```

If the file is named `rotate.sh` and your data `whatever.csv`, you can invoke is as

```
bash rotate.sh whatever.csv
```

This will print the modified file to your terminal. If you want to save it somewhere, write this.

```
bash rotate.sh whatever.csv > /tmp/a.csv
```

Do not write the following

```
bash rotate.sh whatever.csv > whatever.csv
```

The script above is not capable of modifying the same file it is reading from.

The example `sed` script provided by @lurker will work on Linux. If you type this into the command line literally, it will modify the file in place.

```
 sed -i "s/^\([0-9]*\),\(.*\)$/\2,c\1/" whatever.csv
```

The OS X equivalent of that command is

```
 sed -i '' "s/^\([0-9]*\),\(.*\)$/\2,c\1/" whatever.csv
```

Comment: does not meet the needs, and doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach using cut and paste:

```
$ paste -d, <( cut -d, -f2- names.txt )   <( cut -d, -f1 names.txt | sed 's/^/c/' )
james,hard,fun,circle,c0
caron,hard,agin,square,c1
```

Of course, you can turn that into a script by replacing names.txt with $1 as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
paste -d, <( cut -d, -f2- $1 )   <( cut -d, -f1 $1 | sed 's/^/c/' )
```

Or if you really want to prompt the user:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Please specify a file to rearrange:"
read filename
paste -d, <( cut -d, -f2- $filename )   <( cut -d, -f1 $filename | sed 's/^/c/' )
```

If you want to validate that the file entered by the user is valid:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Please specify a file to rearrange:"
read filename
if [ -r "$filename" ] ; then  # is the file readable?
    paste -d, <( cut -d, -f2- $filename )   <( cut -d, -f1 $filename | sed 's/^/c/' )
else
  echo "'$filename' is not readable." >&2  # let them know its bad via stderr
fi
```

Comment: thanks for the help, im about to give you the answer but could you include a error msg if the filename is missing, or if its not found?

Comment: also your code prints out a 9 infront of the number

Comment: Im referring to the last example you made with the please specify

Comment: I have 9999 entrys and yours starts at 9000 not at the beginning which is a 0

Comment: "could you include an error message"? ***Seriously!?!***  I'm sorry, genuinely, I don't mean to be negative, but there was no attempt, no MCVE, and now you are asking for customized error responses? Some of the responsibility for your homework has to actually be yours...